# Recommendation of papers, or reading materials on ${\cal N}=2$, ${\cal N}=4$ supersymmetry

Tags: resource-recommendations, supersymmetry, seiberg-witten-theory

I am familiar with N=1 susy in the context of Wess and Bagger. 
For further progress, i want to study ${\cal N}=2$, ${\cal N}=4$ supersymmetry, to study seiberg-like duality. 
(I am not familiar with the notation ${\cal N}=(2,2)$, ${\cal N}=(0,2)$, what is this left sides and right sides implies?)

Please recommend good materials related to ${\cal N}=2$, ${\cal N}=4$, supersymmetry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found some interesting papers for $N=2$ by Yuji Tachikawa (N-2 supersymmetric dynamcis for dummies, recently revised to N=2 supersymmetric dynamics for pedestrian : arXiv 1312.2684v2)
and some advanced supersymmetric textbook contains extended supersymmetry well.
Also these topics are related with Seiberg-witten theory, review papers on Seiberg-witten theory such as arXiv 9611190, and other online resources will also helpful.

i.e) Terning's Modern supersymmetry textbooks is another good reference which contain advanced topics (extended supersymmetry, Seiberg-witten theory and so on)